# Publish ASP.Net MVC application without .exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

After I publish my ASP.Net application using Visual Studio 2015 to my web host I get Access denied when I type the adress in the browser.

I called my web host support and asked why and he told me they don't allow .exe files, and there is .exe files inside my bin/roslyn folder.

How do I publish my project without the .exe files?

**Update:**

After reading the comments i found that my project is actually using Owin. I tried following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31665196/asp-net-mvc-5-without-owin) but when I try to uninstall Owin I get error: *SignalR Core is dependent on Owin*.

Is it not possible to use SignalR without self-hosting the web page with Owin?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513387/disabling-the-vshost-exe-and-miscellaneous-files-from-being-created-on-build. Have you tried this?

Comment: @shanavascet I can't find how I switch to Release configuration and I don't have a Debug tab in my project Properties? I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx) How-to telling _Projects that do not produce executables do not have this option_, but my project obviously produce executables?

Comment: Is this web site using owin instead of iis?  I think if you are using a web host you need your website to be using iis

Comment: @KenTucker My web hosting company is according to the web host information using Windows / IIS

Comment: I was thing since you have an exe for the web site it is using owin which self hosted not iis.